# Nuget keeps adding repositories.config in source control (TFS) regardless of disableSourceControlIntegration flag

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Nuget seems to stubbornly ignore the flag inside .nuget/nuget.config file. It's important to note that no actual packages are being added to the source control, just the annoying repositories.config.

I can confirm that our settings are correct, and if I remove the flag from the .nuget folder, then also packages start being added.

The only reference to my problem I could find here - https://github.com/Haacked/NuGet/pull/2. But it seems that this pull request is made in a clone repository.

For reference we are using VS 2013 with TFS 2013 with latest updates. We use server workspaces and I couldn't make .tfignore file work probably due to that.

Has anyone experienced that problem and if so, how did you overcome with it?

Answer (score 1):

we use a .tfignore file for this. Here's a blog on how to do it:
http://blog.appliedis.com/2014/11/06/excluding-files-from-team-foundation-version-control-using-tfignore-files/